# How to Keep Multiple Tables Beside Each Other Under a Section?

Tags: tables, floats

I want to represent 3 tables beside each other under the same section. But whatever I tried to do, `\FloatBarrier` never seemed to do anything.

Keeping the 3 tables beside each other is done using `minipage`s (as shown by multiple answers on this sight):

```
\begin{table}
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \caption{First Trial \label{tab: Table 1}}
      \bigskip
      \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
        >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
        \toprule
        \(x\) (cm) & \(t\) (s) \\
        \midrule
        100 & 5.66 \\
        90 & 4.81 \\
        80 & 4.34 \\
        70 & 3.26 \\
        60 & 3.00 \\
        50 & 2.79 \\
        40 & 2.27 \\
        30 & 1.69 \\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
  \quad
  % Second trial
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \caption{Second Trial \label{tab: Table 2}}
      \bigskip
      \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
        >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
        \toprule
        \(x\) (cm) & \(t\) (s) \\
        \midrule
        100 & 5.66 \\
        90 & 4.81 \\
        80 & 4.34 \\
        70 & 3.26 \\
        60 & 3.00 \\
        50 & 2.79 \\
        40 & 2.27 \\
        30 & 1.69 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
  \quad
  % Third trial
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \caption{Third Trial \label{tab: Table 3}}
      \bigskip
      \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
        >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
        \toprule
        \(x\) (cm) & \(t\) (s) \\
        \midrule
        100 & 5.66 \\
        90 & 4.81 \\
        80 & 4.34 \\
        70 & 3.26 \\
        60 & 3.00 \\
        50 & 2.79 \\
        40 & 2.27 \\
        30 & 1.69 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

---

Possible unrelated question: **Why do the tables stack up on each other when I add a newline between the `quads`, like this**:

```
% First trial
\begin{table}
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \caption{First Trial \label{tab: Table 1}}
      \bigskip
      \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
        >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
        \toprule
        \(x\) (cm) & \(t\) (s) \\
        \midrule
        100 & 5.66 \\
        90 & 4.81 \\
        80 & 4.34 \\
        70 & 3.26 \\
        60 & 3.00 \\
        50 & 2.79 \\
        40 & 2.27 \\
        30 & 1.69 \\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}

  \quad

  % Second trial
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \caption{Second Trial \label{tab: Table 2}}
      \bigskip
      \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
        >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
        \toprule
        \(x\) (cm) & \(t\) (s) \\
        \midrule
        100 & 5.66 \\
        90 & 4.81 \\
        80 & 4.34 \\
        70 & 3.26 \\
        60 & 3.00 \\
        50 & 2.79 \\
        40 & 2.27 \\
        30 & 1.69 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}

  \quad

  % Third trial
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \caption{Third Trial \label{tab: Table 3}}
      \bigskip
      \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
        >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
        \toprule
        \(x\) (cm) & \(t\) (s) \\
        \midrule
        100 & 5.66 \\
        90 & 4.81 \\
        80 & 4.34 \\
        70 & 3.26 \\
        60 & 3.00 \\
        50 & 2.79 \\
        40 & 2.27 \\
        30 & 1.69 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

I thought whitespace didn't matter.

---

Anyways, as many answers indicate over here, `\FloatBarrier` from `placein` could be used in order to keep figures, tables, and other stuff in their desired sections. However, when I add a `\FloatBarrier` just before I type `\end{table}`, nothing changes. In fact, wherever I add `\FloatBarrier` in the `table` environment, nothing changes. **Why doesn't `\FloatBarrier` have any effect here?**

Lastly, how could I keep multiple tables beside each other and under the same section?

**EDIT:** Sorry for not providing a MWE from the beginning

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
The tables below provide data.

% First trial
    \begin{table}
      \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
          \caption{First Trial \label{tab: Table 1}}
          \bigskip
          \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
            >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
            \toprule
            \(x\) (cm) & \(t\) (s) \\
            \midrule
            100 & 5.66 \\
            90 & 4.81 \\
            80 & 4.34 \\
            70 & 3.26 \\
            60 & 3.00 \\
            50 & 2.79 \\
            40 & 2.27 \\
            30 & 1.69 \\
          \bottomrule
          \end{tabularx}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage}
      \quad
      % Second trial
      \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
          \caption{Second Trial \label{tab: Table 2}}
          \bigskip
          \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
            >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
            \toprule
            \(x\) (cm) & \(t\) (s) \\
            \midrule
            100 & 4.43 \\
            90 & 4.10 \\
            80 & 3.44 \\
            70 & 3.32 \\
            60 & 3.12 \\
            50 & 2.54 \\
            40 & 2.33 \\
            30 & 1.56 \\
            \bottomrule
          \end{tabularx}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage}
      \quad
      % Third trial
      \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
          \caption{Third Trial \label{tab: Table 3}}
          \bigskip
          \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
            >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
            \toprule
            \(x\) (cm) & \(t\) (s) \\
            \midrule
            100 & 4.95 \\
            90 & 4.75 \\
            80 & 3.71 \\
            70 & 3.64 \\
            60 & 3.19 \\
            50 & 2.47 \\
            40 & 1.88 \\
            30 & 1.31 \\
            \bottomrule
          \end{tabularx}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that others can use to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: Did you already try to use the optional argument of the `table` environment? See also the part about "Float placement specifiers"  in the answer to [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/134144)

Comment: Since you mention the issue that empty lines between minipages results in stacked instead of side-by-side minipages and even show a corresponding part of code, here: What exactly is the issue here? You already seem to know how to avoid it...

Comment: Some off-topic comments about the code already provided: Using the `center` environment to horizontally center contents inside of a `table` environment will lead to additional white space. You may want to replace it with the `\centering` command. Also, what's the point of `tabularx` here? A simple `\begin{tabular}{lr}` should work perfectly fine for this type of tables.  For improved and uniform spacing around captions, I'd also load the `caption` package and remove all occurences of `\bigskip`.

Comment: For an improved (more even) horizontal distribution of the individual tables, you may either want to replace `\quad` with `\hfill` or add `\centering` withg before the first `minipage` environment. (You can add `\usepackage{showframe}` (draws lines tovisualize the textblock/margins) to the preamble to see the effect.)

Comment: @leandriis The issue is that I cannot seem to have them beside each other and, at the same time, under the same section.

Comment: a minitable is positioned by the same code that positions a letter such as `X`  if you use `XXX` they touch, if you use `X X X` they have space between and go side by side or wrap to the next line if they do not fit and if you go `X blank line X blank line X` then they are in three paragraphs so stack vertically.

Comment: FloadBarrier will do nothing if used inside a table and will do nothing to adjust the positions of minipages within a table.

Comment: Is it sensible for minipages that are 0.3 \textwidth to contain tables that are 075 \textwidth?

Comment: @Bernard but the inner textwidths are different (they are the width of the minipage)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I thought \textwidth always referred to the document \textwith. So this was a wrong thought?

Comment: @Bernard it is the specified width inside a minipage  (that's really the origin of the name, it acts like a smaller page, unlike `\parbox` that just boxes its content.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not provided any code that shows the issue but your first code block has a `table` containing a single paragraph that has

`minitable` `space` `quad` `minitable` `space` `quad` `minitable`

with the spaces coming from the end of line after `\end{minitable}`.

Usually a space is around .3em so the total width here is .9\textwidth+ 2.6em  so this will fit on one line or wrap to two lines at the second `space` depending on whether or not  .9\textwidth+ 2.6em is less than \textwidth.

Your second table has 3 paragraphs

`minitable`
paragraph break and discarded horizontal skip
`minitable`
paragraph break and discarded horizontal skip
`minitable`

so the three paragraphs appear vertically.

As you see, white space matters in both these cases it is adding inter-word space in the first case and paragraph breaks in the second.

The purpose of the `table` environment is to allow the content to be moved. You have not said what document class you are using but most default the position to `[tbp]` which would not allow it to be placed where it is in the source, under a heading, that is the `h` (here) position so use `[htbp]` which will then not move the table if it fits under the heading.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}


\section{Some section}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
      \caption{First Trial \label{tab: Table 1}}
      \bigskip
      \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}[t]{
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
        >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
        \toprule
        \(x\) (cm) & \(t\) (s) \\
        \midrule
        100 & 5.66 \\
        90 & 4.81 \\
        80 & 4.34 \\
        70 & 3.26 \\
        60 & 3.00 \\
        50 & 2.79 \\
        40 & 2.27 \\
        30 & 1.69 \\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
   \centering
      \caption{Second Trial \label{tab: Table 2}}
      \bigskip
      \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}[t]{
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
        >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
        \toprule
        \(x\) (cm) & \(t\) (s) \\
        \midrule
        100 & 5.66 \\
        90 & 4.81 \\
        80 & 4.34 \\
        70 & 3.26 \\
        60 & 3.00 \\
        50 & 2.79 \\
        40 & 2.27 \\
        30 & 1.69 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  % Third trial
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
 \centering
      \caption{Third Trial \label{tab: Table 3}}
      \bigskip
      \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}[t]{
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
        >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
        \toprule
        \(x\) (cm) & \(t\) (s) \\
        \midrule
        100 & 5.66 \\
        90 & 4.81 \\
        80 & 4.34 \\
        70 & 3.26 \\
        60 & 3.00 \\
        50 & 2.79 \\
        40 & 2.27 \\
        30 & 1.69 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: note that I would not use tabularx here there is no line breacing, if you use `tabular` with `{rrr}` columns so the tables were set their natural widths the _x_ cm would not break over two lines and the numeric data would be alighened even if you had an entry such as 10.12

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will update the code to form a MWE. But may I ask, what does `hfill` do, and how does it differ from `quad`?

Comment: @BoredComedy hfill is a space that stretches as much as necessary so the three tables will be as far apart as possible. `\quad` is a fixed width of `1em` so you are positioning the tables at fixed positions from the left with the right margin being whatever space is left

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. From where does the argument `[tbp]` come from? And what's the point of `\FloatBarrier` then? Sorry if these are amateur questions but I've got some holes in my knowledge of LaTeX.

Comment: @BoredComedy tbp is core latex it should be described in any latex tutorial, sorry the site format really doesn't support asking multiple questions as comments on an existing one. FloatBarrier is used in the main document not in `table` enviornment and stops floats such as tables moving past that point, it is not relevant to the issue as you have described it.